# WinSCP process terminated with exit code 3 and output ""

Tags: winscp, winscp-net

Our .NET application uses WinSCP software to work with SFTP servers. It's running on different machines, however 1 week ago 2 of them started to fail with the following exception:

**WinSCP.SessionLocalException, WinSCP process terminated with exit code 3 and output "", without responding (response log file D:\local\Temp\wscp1028.00ADA812.tmp was not created). This could indicate lack of write permissions to the log folder or problems starting WinSCP itself., 
at WinSCP.Session.Open(SessionOptions sessionOptions)**

This error doesn't occur always, but after some period of time. Once error occurs it fails always until we restart the entire application. After application restart it successfully works 10-20 hours and approx. 15K-30K succeeded requests. Then the error starts again.

We have already upgraded to the last version of WinSCP (**5.7.7**) and restarted the machines, however the issue still takes place. What could be the root cause and what steps could be done to fix the issue? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you `.Dispose` the session?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Yes, every object of Session type is disposed (it's created in `using` statement).

Comment: Do I understand right that you create tens of thousands of `Session` instances a day?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Yes, we create approx. 10,000 - 30,000 `Session` instances per day.

Comment: Sorry for late answer. It took me while to find a time to test this. Though I was able to open 100K sessions over a span on about 24 hours in a single application run without any problem.

Comment: Can you try to use the [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor) to debug the failing start of `winscp.exe`?

Comment: The root cause is that there was no enough disk space since other instances of winscp.exe were downloading large files.

Comment: You should not get exit code 3 in this case. Are you sure you were getting this exit code when you run out of disk space?

Comment: did you get final solution ? ***10,000 - 30,000 Session instances per day*** ??